# How to get event logs from either eth_call or debug_traceCall in Geth?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm curious if anyone here could shed some light on this problem. I have been using ganache-core to dry run transactions. Unfortunately, it's way too slow for my use. Geth's eth_call is comparatively very fast, however it does not return event logs, which I need.

I have played with debug_Tracecall, but it seems like massive overkill, is relatively slow (though faster than Ganache), and I can't seem to figure out how to extract event logs from the returned values even assuming that they are there.

Does anyone know how to get event logs from eth_call, or at least know how to get them from the returned values on eth_Tracecall?

Answer (score 0):

[eth_call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) does not produce a transaction. An [event](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/contracts.html#events) log, on the other hand, is emitted and stored to the blockchain as a result of a transaction.

So what you're asking, is simply impossible by design.

---

But assuming that the called contract function is defined to emit an event, you can execute a transaction (instead of the call), which will emit the event.

Then you'll be able to get the event logs using the [eth_getTransactionReceipt](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_gettransactionreceipt) method, under the `logs` array.

Comment: Thats not accurate. You can debug_traceCall with a custom tracer and extract event logs from VM state. All you need is to peek stack everytime you see LOGX opcode

Comment: @deadlock The OP explicitly stated that `debug_Tracecall` "seems like massive overkill" and "is relatively slow". But feel free to post your own answer with another solution using `debug_tradeCall`.